# ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW on sum column

Tags: sql, grouping

[image]how can i add
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW on sum  column?
because the lead/lag function dont work

used the cod :

```
select year (orderdate),month (orderdate),sum (SubTotal),
lead ( sum (SubTotal),0) OVER ( PARTITION BY sum (SubTotal) ORDER BY  sum (SubTotal) ) as PrevOrder
from sales.SalesOrderHeader
where orderdate <= '2011-12-31'
group by 
 grouping sets 
  ((year (orderdate),month (orderdate)),  () )
```

and add a  name to the row total sum ?

added the expected output the table to extract the data and my query [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UYfu.jpg)[my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DGzT.jpg)
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm703.jpg)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. And note that most people here want formatted text, not images. (One reason is that images make copy-and-paste impossible.)

Comment: thanks next time i will

Comment: Why do you need that record with 'grand_total' value in month column?

Comment: i dont need to :) i was asked to ad 'grand_total' value in month , add eventually to the year column 2011+''+ 'grand_total' and solved it with openinig 2 ctes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.